# Storing data from obtained from loop

Tags: matlab

Suppose a MATLAB program is written as:

```
c=5;
a=4.5;
m=14;
for i=1:14
    a=c*a;
end
```

How do I store the values of `a`? I wish to use the values of `a` later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store previous values of `a` in an array. You can pre-allocate the array outside of your loop and then fill it each time through your loop.

```
a = zeros(1, 15);
a(1) = 4.5;

for k = 1:14
    a(k + 1) = c * a(k);
end

last_a = a(end);
```

Answer (score 0):

A short form of @Suever's answer, can be written like that:

```
c=5;
a=4.5*c.^(0:14);
```

The results are:

```
a=
4.50000000000000    22.5000000000000    112.500000000000    562.500000000000    2812.50000000000    14062.5000000000    70312.5000000000  .......
```